# CodeIgniter model not getting all status values

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my model in code igniter, I'm trying to query a database and get all rows where the status column is not equal to 2. This column or field can be either 0, 1, or 2.

In my code I use:

```
$this->db->where([

    'referral_status' => !2

    ]); 

  $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
```

However, It's only  pulling out the rows that have status = 0. It's not also getting rows where status = 1. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: !2===false. so it will pull out the data where `referral_status=false` means `referral_status=0`

Comment: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should do like this

```
$this->db->where("your_id !=",$your_id);
```

if this does not work for you please let me know and don't forget to rate the answer

Comment: Thanks so much! I got it with `$this->db->where('referrals.referral_status != 2')` I didn't need to add a parameter because I'm not passing one into the public function. I up voted this but I need one more rep point for the vote to display.

Comment: its ok .. but  i was  in desperate need of repo

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->where([

    'referral_status !=' => 2

    ]); 

  $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
```

You have mistakenly put the `!`.  Also you need the `=`.

See codeigniter [docu](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html)